# Why is CSV export missing in my SSRS report?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a few SSRS reports running on SQL Server 2008 Web Edition SP1 on my production web server.

For some reason, CSV and XML export is not offered to me when viewing my reports in the report viewer. This applies to all reports on that server.

As you can see, PDF, Word and Excel still work fine, it's just XML and CSV that are missing:

[image: Screenshot of my report export options]

The reports are rendered on the server side, so that can't be the problem.

I checked rsreportserver.config and the xml and csv export formats are at least still mentioned there in the `<Render>` node. I am not sure if this is all I need for CSV and XML export to work though:

```
    <Render>
            <Extension Name="XML" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.DataRenderer.XmlDataReport,Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataRendering"/>
            <Extension Name="NULL" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.NullRenderer.NullReport,Microsoft.ReportingServices.NullRendering" Visible="false"/>
            <Extension Name="CSV" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.DataRenderer.CsvReport,Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataRendering"/>
            <Extension Name="PDF" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.PDFRenderer,Microsoft.ReportingServices.ImageRendering"/>
            <Extension Name="RGDI" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.RGDIRenderer,Microsoft.ReportingServices.ImageRendering" Visible="false"/>
            <Extension Name="HTML4.0" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.Html40RenderingExtension,Microsoft.ReportingServices.HtmlRendering" Visible="false"/>
            <Extension Name="MHTML" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.MHtmlRenderingExtension,Microsoft.ReportingServices.HtmlRendering"/>
            <Extension Name="EXCEL" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ExcelRenderer.ExcelRenderer,Microsoft.ReportingServices.ExcelRendering"/>
            <Extension Name="RPL" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.RPLRendering.RPLRenderer,Microsoft.ReportingServices.RPLRendering" Visible="false" LogAllExecutionRequests="false"/>
            <Extension Name="IMAGE" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.ImageRenderer,Microsoft.ReportingServices.ImageRendering"/>
            <Extension Name="WORD" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.WordRenderer.WordDocumentRenderer,Microsoft.ReportingServices.WordRendering"/>
    </Render>
```

So, what could be the problem here and how do I fix it?

Thanks,

Adrian

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After several tests and posts to the MSDN forums I have finally learned that this is not a bug, but a limitation to the web edition of MS SQL Server. Unlike the Standard edition and higher, it is not supposed to support additional export formats, even though these are listed in the .config file.

Comment: Does anyone have an official source from MS that confirms this? (SQL Server editions comparison doesn't mention XML/CSV)
http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/product-info/compare.aspx -> Reporting -> Export to Excel, Word, PDF, and images. It doesn't mention HTML, but it is possible to export to HTML...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's some problem with the language localization...?

Have you tried adding a custom extension with another name to check to see if it shows up?  Have you tried removing any from the RSReportServer.config file to see if they disappear from the front-end?  These seem like possible ways to at least troubleshoot the behavior.